# symfony 4 where to remove big part from controller's action

Tags: php, symfony, oop, model-view-controller

I'm using symfony 4 and want to remove big part from controller's action to another method. But in this part using data from `Request` object and return `Response` object.

I have 2 options to move this part:

1. Move to private method in controller.
2. Move in service method.

And i have 2 options, what to do with method parameters:

1. Set `Request` object as method's argument and get all data from it in method.
2. Get all data from `Request` object in controller's action and set it as method's arguments.

Which way is better and why? Maybe there is a better way?

Is it normal practice to return `Response` object to controller's action from service method?

**Code example:**

```
public function index(Request $request): Response
{
    if(!$this->hasSuccessAuth($request)) {
        return $this->authenticateClient();
    }

}

private function hasSuccessAuth(Request $request): bool
{
    $passwordCookie = $request->cookies->get('secret', NULL);

    if(self::CHECK_AUTH_MODE === $request->query->get('mode') and
        $this->authService->isCorrectPasswordCookie($passwordCookie)) {

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

private function authenticateClient(): Response
{
    if($this->authService->isSuccessHttpAuth()) {

        $passwordForCookie = $this->authService->getPassword();

        return new Response("success\nsecret\n".$passwordForCookie."\n");
    }

    return new Response('', Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have 2 options to move this part:
>
> 1. Move to private method in controller.
> 2. Move in service method.

You can move into private method in controller or in service method in fact. If you move to private method in controller, my advices is that you should create a wrapper controller class that your controller will extend and you put this private method inside. Obviously this controller will extends the base Symfony Controller if your initial controller already extended it. This can be good if you intend to use **hasSuccessAuth** and **authenticateClient** with other controller classes only. Because if you put this logic in a service, other services or command will be able to use it. It is up to you.

If now you want this logic to be accessed everywhere in you application, better create a service. But you should ask yourself, if this new service will have its own data or will benefit from dependency injection. If yes, creating a service is a good idea. If no, that means you will use this logic only to deal with data given as parameters and return a result. In this case you should create a helper class with static methods.

> And i have 2 options, what to do with method parameters:
>
> 1. Set Request object as method's argument and get all data from it in method.
> 2. Get all data from Request object in controller's action and set it as method's arguments.

It is up to you but if it was my application, I would chosen to give the entire Request object as argument of the method and all data from it inside the method.

And one last thing: your **authenticateClient** method does not use the **Request** object.